# arrange columns of multiple tables mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a database with hundreds of the same tables however not all tables have the same column order. I don't know which tables and I don't know what order they are in, only that the columns are the same for every table. Is there a way to rearrange all columns in a table? I know with the Alter statement you can rearrange one column but I would like to to all columns at once for a table.

EDIT:
I would need to do this for all tables using the table_schema and then create a query for all. So exporting the database and changing the create table isn't an option since I would need to change it for all tables.

Comment: If you don’t have excessive amounts of data in those tables, then I’d probably just go for an export, modify the CREATE TABLE statements in there to have the columns in the “right” order, and then import the whole thing again …

Comment: @CBroe Thanks but this is not an option, please see my edit in the question.

Comment: If you export structure and data separately, then you just have to copy&paste your CREATE TABLE statement as many times as you have tables, and just modify the table name … after that, data can be imported again, if you chose the export option of generating INSERT statements that include the columns names (that way their order doesn’t matter.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to CBroe here is a solution:

make an export of only the data of the database and create a new database.

Then run this query in the information_schema:

```
SELECT CONCAT("Create Table `db_new`.`", TABLE_NAME, "` LIKE `db_old`.`default` ;") as MySQLCMD FROM TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_old'
```

Then execute all these queries which are generated for you to create all the tables with the same structure (default table).

Then import the data in the new database.